# How to Import Script with Powershell command

Tags: powershell

i try to import a certificate with a command found on microsoft help. the command is
Import-RDWebClientBrokerCert <.cer file path> , but i can't get what to write in the file path part <.cer file path>. what ever i wrote had a error...

thankful for any hint, help, idea.

i' am following this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-web-client-admin#what-youll-need-to-set-up-the-web-client

Comment: Please consider adding the error to include what it is you're trying to accomplish with the command itself

Comment: Why are you installing a certificate instead of using a public certificate?  If you need to install a non public certificate than you need the certificate file and the path is the location where the certificate file is located.  Is the file on the local client, or remote machine?  The certificate should be on the local machine.

Comment: The linked tutorial states: "run this cmdlet with the bracketed value [i.e. `<.cer file path>`] replaced with the path of the `.cer` file that you copied from the RD Broker"

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in, as text, the code you are running. Please include any error messages as text. No pictures.